# wsus, installed, not applicable updates

Tags: wsus

We're implementing WSUS and have a test group set up with both a Windows 7 Pro and an XP Pro machine.  The issue we are having at this time is that the Windows 7 machine is showing as up to date in the WSUS console and if you go to Windows Update.  But if you manually search for updates through Windows Update it comes up with 77 available.  I can see all of the updates in WSUS but they are showing as installed or not applicable but I know they aren't installed and are definitely applicable!  Any ideas out there?

Comment: Have you approved some of the updates for installation on your machines?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the [Windows Update Log File](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902093) for signs of any problems. This should point you in the right direction. Without more information, it's impossible to provide you with a more specific answer.

Maybe if you get some clues from the log file, but you are still struggling, you could edit your question to include any new information that you find.