# WSUS Content folder not retaining updates

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus

I have been scratching my head now for a while over this issue and anything I do will not solve the problem

**The Problem:**

> WSUS' "WSUSContent" folder is self-deleting updates and reducing the
>   overall size to <5GB. The original size was over 300GB. ***Where have the
>   updates gone? We did not initiate a WSUSContent cleanup nor have we in the past.***

**Attempts at solving:**

```
WSUSutil /reset.
Reinstall WSUS service from scratch.
Migrated from internal database to remote SQL database.
```

**Further Information:**

- The WSUS database is located on a remote SQL server
- WSUSutil reset rebuilt the whole content folder to over 300GB.
- WSUS was active for a period of time (1-2 weeks) and then suddenly stopped working within one day (unfortunately, we don't know when this happened)
- Frequently after this issue occurs, we get the generic 800 code for WSUS missing content:

> 2015-03-30    14:25:19:174    1184    195c    Setup   FATAL: GetClientUpdateUrl
>   failed, err = 0x8024D009
>   2015-03-30    14:25:19:174    1184    195c    Setup   Skipping SelfUpdate check
>   based on the /SKIP directive in wuident
>   2015-03-30    14:25:19:174    1184    195c    Setup   SelfUpdate check completed. 
>   SelfUpdate is NOT required.

- There is no scheduled task to "cleanup" the updates and we automatically approve all updates for the required technologies (Windows 7, 8.1, Server 2012, SQL 2012, and others which have eluded me off the top of my head).
- We have used third-party tools to check our WSUS setup and they all return with the claim that the setup is fine and no problems were detected.
- We have WSUS working on HTTP and HTTPS, SSL certificate is fine and within date/valid.
- When connecting with Administrator tools to WSUS, the console periodically will break and display a red "X" and state that the remote API stopped working? (I am pasting below another error which the WSUS administration console experiences):

> The WSUS administration console has encountered an unexpected error.
>   This may be a transient error; try restarting the administration
>   console. If this error persists,
>
> Try removing the persisted preferences for the console by deleting the
>   wsus file under %appdata%\Microsoft\MMC.
>
> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException -- The given key was
>   not present in the dictionary.
>
> Source mscorlib
>
> Stack Trace:    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)    at
>   Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.SnapIn.Pages.UpdatesListPage.GetUpdateRow(WsusUpdate
>   update)    at
>   Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.SnapIn.Pages.UpdatesListPage.GetListRows()

- I have followed these on SF, to no luck:

[WSUS not receiving updates?](https://serverfault.com/questions/377106/wsus-not-receiving-updates)
&
[WSUS, installed, not applicable](https://serverfault.com/questions/353827/wsus-installed-not-applicable-updates)

Many others on the internet also to try and find an answer.

- The WSUS server is part of a domain and to clarify, when I ran wsusutil /reset, all clients connected were getting updates and connectivity is not an issue, WSUS content just disappears with no trace.

**Windows Log File "Red" Entries:**

These are the critical log entries I have tried looking into, to no avail also, unless I am overlooking something..

- 376 1b0c    Misc    WARNING: Network Cost is assumed to be not supported as something failed with trying to get handles to wcmapi.dll
- Report   WARNING: Reporter failed to upload events with hr = 8007000d.
- WARNING: Failed converting event batch to web service event: 0x8007000d
- FATAL: GetClientUpdateUrl failed, err = 0x8024D009
- WARNING: Failed to get Wu Exemption info from NLM, assuming not exempt, error = 0x80240037
- Agent      * Online = No; Ignore download priority = No **<- Online = No; ???**

Any help would be appreciated as this is just very unusual to happen.

Comment: Have you checked the server for malware?

Comment: Yes. We have SCEP running and nothing has been found. No abnormalities also in traffic or logs.

Comment: Have you installed the available updates to WSUS itself? Currently you need KB2828185 and KB2938066 to be up to date. The former package also rolls up 4 additional fixes (2530678, 2530709, 2720211, & 2734608). These address quite a few WSUS issues, and I wouldn't spend a minute of time troubleshooting a problem before installing them.

Comment: The latter package was already installed over a month ago according to the Get-Hotfix cmdlet. The issue occurred afterwards. The former package/individual hotfixes do not apply to Windows Server 2012 unfortunately.

Comment: What's the scope of update languages you have selected? Are you just pulling English updates, or do you have it set to download in all languages? Also, are you only downloading approved updates, or are you pulling everything? 300GB is pretty massive content folder to see on a freshly rebuilt WSUS instance. I rebuilt one of mine a few weeks back, and I'm at <10GB with around 1,000 approved updates.

Comment: Only English updates and we hgave an auto-approval rule for the technologies listed in our product list (Windows 7, Windows 8, Server 2008, 2012, SQL server, SCEP, 3rd-party drivers (display adapters, and that usual jazz)). I was surprised as well that it amounted to 300GB but it suddenly just reduced to 0.99GB and updates can no longer be found.

Comment: Hmm, I'm inclined to think you're running into some kind of WSUS limitation that I'm not aware of, but let's first look into why that content folder is so huge, because you have a pretty typical setup, and shouldn't be seeing that much data initially. If you start in the all updates view and filter by 'approved' and 'any status', how many are shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, odd fix.

My WSUSContent folder had 0.99GB in it and after a manual server cleanup(did not select unneeded update files) waited about 45 minutes and then selecting unneeded update files..another minute goes by, the WSUSContent folder is at 100GB (from 0.99GB, the internet speed is not fast enough here to grab 99GB in <45 minutes) and 50,000 updates are approved.

It works though. Very, very strange. Nothing in logs requested a cleanup, nor was space an issue. How very bizarre.

Thank you all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Can I echo what @Proxy said:

> odd fix ... Very, very strange. ... How very bizarre.

My Samsung laptop has Windows 8.1-Update. It had an infection that was cleaned. Current date is 05/16/2017 but last windows update was 2 years ago back in 2015.

Windows updates were not working after it was cleaned of malware. It would hang, no progress in `c:\windows\WindowsUpdate.log`, and yet taking up 100% of one core.

One consequence of being 2 years out of date, that might be relevant, was that GWX (Get Windows 10) was still running on this laptop, even tho that offer expired over 1 year ago.

The other notable thing with this laptop was that I replaced the motherboard twice. The first time, it was crashing multiple times a day. The second motherboard worked fine. So those crashes may have had an effect here.

After trying almost everything, this is what worked: Windows `cleanmgr.exe` aka "Disk Cleanup" aka "Clean up disk space by deleting unnecessary files".

I selected:

- Temporary Internet Files
- Debug Dump Files (looks like they're still there, though)
- System Error Memory Dump Files (looks like they're still there, though)
- Temporary Files

After that, and a reboot, Windows Update worked. How very bizarre.

Here's some of the prominent solutions I tried that didn't work:

```
:: consider carefully /ResetBase -- it prevents you from un-installing windows updates
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
sfc /scannow
```

I had to run those more than once.
Each of those steps fixed corruption. Until they passed with no corruption found.

Still, Windows Update would not work. Still hung.

Going deeper I tried this fix, "Option 2" from sevenforums https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/91738-windows-update-reset.html :

```
Reset_Reregister_Windows_Update_Components.bat
```

Here's the contents of that batch file as of today:

```
@echo off

:: Created by: Shawn Brink
:: http://www.sevenforums.com
:: Tutorial: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/91738-windows-update-reset.html


set b=0

:bits
set /a b=%b%+1
if %b% equ 3 (
   goto end1
) 
net stop bits
echo Checking the bits service status.
sc query bits | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto bits 
) 
goto loop2

:end1
cls
echo.
echo Failed to reset Windows Update due to bits service failing to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start


:loop2
set w=0

:wuauserv
set /a w=%w%+1
if %w% equ 3 (
   goto end2
) 
net stop wuauserv
echo Checking the wuauserv service status.
sc query wuauserv | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto wuauserv 
) 
goto loop3

:end2
cls
echo.
echo Failed to reset Windows Update due to wuauserv service failing to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start



:loop3
set app=0

:appidsvc
set /a app=%app%+1
if %app% equ 3 (
   goto end3
) 
net stop appidsvc
echo Checking the appidsvc service status.
sc query appidsvc | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto appidsvc 
) 
goto loop4

:end3
cls
echo.
echo Failed to reset Windows Update due to appidsvc service failing to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start


:loop4
set c=0

:cryptsvc
set /a c=%c%+1
if %c% equ 3 (
   goto end4
) 
net stop cryptsvc
echo Checking the cryptsvc service status.
sc query cryptsvc | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto cryptsvc 
) 
goto Reset

:end4
cls
echo.
echo Failed to reset Windows Update due to cryptsvc service failing to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start



:Reset
Ipconfig /flushdns
Del "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Network\Downloader\qmgr*.dat"
sc.exe sdset bits D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)
sc.exe sdset wuauserv D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)
cd /d %windir%\system32
Ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.bak
regsvr32.exe /s atl.dll
regsvr32.exe /s urlmon.dll
regsvr32.exe /s mshtml.dll
regsvr32.exe /s shdocvw.dll
regsvr32.exe /s browseui.dll
regsvr32.exe /s jscript.dll
regsvr32.exe /s vbscript.dll
regsvr32.exe /s scrrun.dll
regsvr32.exe /s msxml.dll
regsvr32.exe /s msxml3.dll
regsvr32.exe /s msxml6.dll
regsvr32.exe /s actxprxy.dll
regsvr32.exe /s softpub.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wintrust.dll
regsvr32.exe /s dssenh.dll
regsvr32.exe /s rsaenh.dll
regsvr32.exe /s gpkcsp.dll
regsvr32.exe /s sccbase.dll
regsvr32.exe /s slbcsp.dll
regsvr32.exe /s cryptdlg.dll
regsvr32.exe /s oleaut32.dll
regsvr32.exe /s ole32.dll
regsvr32.exe /s shell32.dll
regsvr32.exe /s initpki.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuapi.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuaueng.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuaueng1.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wucltui.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wups.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wups2.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuweb.dll
regsvr32.exe /s qmgr.dll
regsvr32.exe /s qmgrprxy.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wucltux.dll
regsvr32.exe /s muweb.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuwebv.dll
regsvr32 /s wudriver.dll
netsh winsock reset

:Start
net start bits
net start wuauserv
net start appidsvc
net start cryptsvc
bitsadmin.exe /reset /allusers
```

I tried an expanded version that added stopping/starting of `msiserver` and a rename of `%systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution` and which stopped `wuauserv` last because windows may auto-re-start it.

Here's that code:

```
:rem v2 with ren whole SoftwareDistribution
:rem    and stop / start msiserver
@echo off

:: Created by: Shawn Brink
:: http://www.sevenforums.com
:: Tutorial: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/91738-windows-update-reset.html


:rem ---------- bits ----------
:loop1
set b=0

:bits
set /a b=%b%+1
if %b% equ 3 (
   goto end1
) 
net stop bits
echo Checking the bits service status.
sc query bits | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto bits 
) 
goto loop2

:end1
cls
echo.
echo Failed to reset Windows Update due to bits service failing to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start


:rem ---------- appidsvc ----------
:loop2
set app=0

:appidsvc
set /a app=%app%+1
if %app% equ 3 (
   goto end2
) 
net stop appidsvc
echo Checking the appidsvc service status.
sc query appidsvc | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto appidsvc 
) 
goto loop3

:end2
cls
echo.
echo Failed to reset Windows Update due to appidsvc service failing to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start


:rem ---------- cryptsvc ----------
:loop3
set c=0

:cryptsvc
set /a c=%c%+1
if %c% equ 3 (
   goto end3
) 
net stop cryptsvc
echo Checking the cryptsvc service status.
sc query cryptsvc | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto cryptsvc 
) 
goto loop4

:end3
cls
echo.
echo Failed to reset Windows Update due to cryptsvc service failing to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start


:rem ---------- msiserver ----------
:loop4
set w=0

:msiserver
set /a w=%w%+1
if %w% equ 3 (
   goto end4
) 
net stop msiserver
echo Checking the msiserver service status.
sc query msiserver | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto msiserver 
) 
goto loop5

:end4
cls
echo.
echo Failed to reset Windows Update due to msiserver service failing to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start


:rem ---------- wuauserv ----------
:loop5
set w=0

:wuauserv
set /a w=%w%+1
if %w% equ 3 (
   goto end5
) 
net stop wuauserv
echo Checking the wuauserv service status.
sc query wuauserv | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto wuauserv 
) 
goto Reset

:end5
cls
echo.
echo Failed to reset Windows Update due to wuauserv service failing to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start



:rem ---------- Reset ----------
:Reset
Ipconfig /flushdns
Del "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Network\Downloader\qmgr*.dat"
sc.exe sdset bits D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)
sc.exe sdset wuauserv D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)
cd /d %windir%\system32
Ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.bak

cd %systemroot%\
ren SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution_mm.bak

regsvr32.exe /s atl.dll
regsvr32.exe /s urlmon.dll
regsvr32.exe /s mshtml.dll
regsvr32.exe /s shdocvw.dll
regsvr32.exe /s browseui.dll
regsvr32.exe /s jscript.dll
regsvr32.exe /s vbscript.dll
regsvr32.exe /s scrrun.dll
regsvr32.exe /s msxml.dll
regsvr32.exe /s msxml3.dll
regsvr32.exe /s msxml6.dll
regsvr32.exe /s actxprxy.dll
regsvr32.exe /s softpub.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wintrust.dll
regsvr32.exe /s dssenh.dll
regsvr32.exe /s rsaenh.dll
regsvr32.exe /s gpkcsp.dll
regsvr32.exe /s sccbase.dll
regsvr32.exe /s slbcsp.dll
regsvr32.exe /s cryptdlg.dll
regsvr32.exe /s oleaut32.dll
regsvr32.exe /s ole32.dll
regsvr32.exe /s shell32.dll
regsvr32.exe /s initpki.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuapi.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuaueng.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuaueng1.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wucltui.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wups.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wups2.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuweb.dll
regsvr32.exe /s qmgr.dll
regsvr32.exe /s qmgrprxy.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wucltux.dll
regsvr32.exe /s muweb.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuwebv.dll
regsvr32 /s wudriver.dll
netsh winsock reset

:Start
net start bits
net start wuauserv
net start appidsvc
net start cryptsvc
net start msiserver
bitsadmin.exe /reset /allusers
```

And after all that what got Windows Update to work again was `cleanmgr`